# My Sublime Text Build System, run build.sh in current folder

Tags: c, macos, latex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Given the following scenario:

I'm editting `document.xyz` and in the same folder there is `build.sh`. I would like Sublime execute `build.sh` when hitting `Ctrl+B`.

The contents of `build.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> date.txt
```

In other words, every time I hit `Ctrl+B`, no matter which document I'm editting, Sublime should print date to `date.txt`.

In order to do that I tried the following (saved it as My.sublime-build):

```
{
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "cmd": ["sh","$file_path/build.sh"],
}
```

Which gives the error:

```
[Errno 24] Too many open files
[cmd: ['sh', '/Users/user/Downloads/test/build.sh']]
[dir: /Users/user/Downloads/test]
[path: /Users/user/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin]
[Finished]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this in your My.sublime-build:

```
{
   "cmd": ["bash","~/<filepath>/build.sh"],
   "selector": "source.shell",
   "shell" : "bash",
   "path": "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
}
```